# Quotient of affine space by cyclic permutation

Tags: invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

The quotient of the affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$ by the symmetric group $Sym_n$ is again an affine space of the same dimension, and invariants are given by elementary symmetric polynomials.

What about a $n$-cycle? More precisely, what are the generators of the invariants of the action of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{A}^n$ given by $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mapsto (x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n,x_1)$ ?

It is probably classical, but I was not able to find it.

Comment: If the  field contains $n$-th roots of 1 and the characteristic does not divide $n$, then up to  a linear change of coordinates the action is $(x_1,\dots  x_n)\mapsto (x_1, \zeta x_2,\dots \zeta^{n-1}x_n)$. 

Comment: ...$\zeta$ is a primitive $n$-th root of 1, of course.


Comment: Yes, I agree. Does it help to give the answer? PS: By the way, I am in fact more interested in the case where the field is $\mathbb{Q}$. But an answer over $\mathbb{C}$ good be a good start.

Comment: @J&#233;r&#233;my: With respect to rita's change of coordinates, which monomials in $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are invariant?  This answers your question.  By the way, if you prove that the invariant ring is $\textit{not}$ a polynomial ring after base change from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, then that also implies that the invariant ring over $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a polynomial ring.

Comment: Also, there is a general theorem, the Chevalley-Shephard-Todd theorem, that answers many similar questions.

Comment: Writing down all the  invariant monomials is easy.  I don't know whether there is a systematic  way of writing down a finite set of generators    and relations. 

Comment: @rita: There are general algorithms for writing down a minimal set of generators for the defining ideal of the semigroup ring of a finitely generated subsemigroup $S$ of the semigroup $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^m$.  A choice of $n$ generators is equivalent to a surjection of semigroups $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n \to S$, or equivalently, a semigroup homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n \to \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^m$.  This determines a $k$-algebra homomorphism of the associated semigroup rings $k[x_1,\dots,x_n] \to k[y_1,\dots,y_m]$.  The defining ideals are each binomials, contd.

Comment: contd. These binomials correspond to a minimal set of generators of the finitely generated semigroup that is the kernel of the semigroup homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n \times \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n \to \mathbb{Z}^m$ that is the "difference" of two copies of the homomorphism above.  

Comment: @Jason: I knew sothing like that had to be known, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. So it seems that the way to do is to work over $\mathbb{C}$, compute the monomials, and come back to get polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$. Seems quite algorithmic, thanks. I do not know if the answer in the end is nice to present, I mean with a formula which is general with $n$ large, but at least it is possible with small $n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rita's answer is perfectly correct.  However, Jérémy posed his question over a (not necessarily algebrically closed) characteristic $0$ field
$k=\mathbb{Q}$, so here is another approach.  Consider the subring $S = k[s_1,\dots,s_n]$ generated by the elementary symmetric polynomials, i.e., the invariant ring under the entire symmetric group, not just the cyclic group.  The entire polynomial ring $R = k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is an $S$-algebra that is, in fact, a 
free $S$-module of rank $n!$.  The fact that this is a free $S$-module follows automatically since $S$ is regular and $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay; however, there are also perfectly explicit choices of $S$-basis, e.g.,
the monomials $\underline{x}^{\underline{e}} =x_1^{e_1}x_2^{e_2}\cdots x_n^{e_n}$ indexed by all exponents $(e_1,\dots,e_n)\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$ with $e_i < i$ for every $i$.  The $k$-algebra homomorphism $$\phi:R\to R, \ \ \phi(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},x_n) = (x_2,\dots,x_n,x_1),$$ is an $S$-algebra homomorphism.  The ring of $\phi$-invariants is the kernel of the $S$-module homomorphism $\text{Id}_R-\phi:R\to R$, which is the same as the image of the "averaging homomorphism" / Maschke homomorphism / Reynolds operator $$E=\frac{1}{n} ( \text{Id} + \phi + \phi^2 + \dots + \phi^{n-1} ).$$
In particular, the subring of $\phi$-invariants is a direct summand of $R$ as an $S$-module.  Of course one set of generators is the set of images $E(\underline{x}^{\underline{e}})$ as above; 
you can compute a smaller set of $S$-generators for the kernel using a term order on $R$ as an $S$-module and using Gröbner basis methods.  Any collection of $S$-generators give $k$-algebra generators once you add in the $k$-algebra generators of $S$, i.e., the elementary symmetric polynomials.

Regarding the question when the ring of invariants is a polynomial ring, or even a smooth $k$-algebra, this fails for all $n\geq 3$.  As explained in the comments, this can be checked after base change to $\overline{k}$, where it becomes an immediate corollary of the Chevalley-Shephard-Todd theorem (or just direct computation).  However, as you can see, the invariant ring is Cohen-Macaulay; it is a free $S$-module (special case of the Hochster-Roberts Theorem).

$\textbf{Edit}$. It seems quite plausible that, as a free $S$-module, the ring of invariants has a basis consisting of $E(\underline{x}^{\underline{e}})$ for those $(n-1)!$ exponents as above satisfying the additional condition that $e_n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

This problem (over an algebraically closed field) has been studied by quite a few people. Rather than repeat myself I'll point you to my answer (and the references there) to this subsequent posing of your question [cyclically symmetric functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125454/cyclically-symmetric-functions/127958#127958)

Working over the rationals introduces an extra level of difficulty.