# Cyclically symmetric functions

Tags: invariant-theory, symmetric-functions, cyclic-groups

Where can I learn about the invariant theory associated with actions of cyclic groups (as opposed to symmetric groups)?

E.g., do the functions $x+y+z$, $xy+yz+zx$, and $x^2y+y^2z+z^2x$ generate the ring of all cyclically-symmetric polynomials in $x$, $y$, and $z$?

Web-accessible and free references would be preferred.

Comment: Probably here: http://garsia.math.yorku.ca/~kenya/enrico.pdf ?

Comment: This reference is extremely well-written, and it covers lots if examples, but the cyclic action on the variables doesn't appear to be one of them (though Theorem 1.17 comes close; it's good to know that for the dihedral action, and all other finite Coxeter group actions, things work out about as nicely as one could hope).

Comment: There is an example with the cyclic group of order 5 in B.Sturmfels' "Algorithms in invariant theory", Sect. 2.7. The latter section has a general treatment of finite abelian groups, too.
It actually looks as if the number of generators of the ring grows quite fast as n increases, e.g. in the case of n=5 you need 11 generators. Counting/finding generators amounts to dealing with certain integer points in a lattice...

B.Sturmfels' "Algorithms in invariant theory" (2nd edition)
ISBN 978-3-211-77416-8 Springer 2008, Wien New-York

Comment: The ring of polynomials invariant under this 3-element cyclic group $G$ cannot be the ring of polynomials in invariants of degree $1,2,3$
because the product of these degrees is $6 \neq |G|$.  In fact
it is known that a finite subgroup $G$ of ${\rm GL}_n({\bf R})$
has an invariant ring generated by only $n$ polynomials
**iff** $G$ is generated by reflections (linear transformations
conjugate to ${\rm diag}(1,1,\ldots,1,-1)$), and the cyclic groups
of order $n>2$ do not satisfy this criterion.


Comment: You need one more degree three generator in the three-variable case, for example $xyz$.

Comment: If you work over the complex numbers, then you can make a linear change of variables so that the monomials in the new variables are eigenvectors. Does this help? 

Comment: The ring of fully symmetric polynomials in three variables is freely generated by $x+y+z$, $xy+xz+yz$, and $xyz$. The element $(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$ is a square root of a polynomial in those three, and surely this yields a presentation of the ring of cyclically invariant functions. 

Comment: This question seems related, if not actually equivalent, to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/14613/invariant-polynomials-under-a-group-action-hidden-git .

Answer (score 2):

A good reference is Richard Stanley's "[Invariants of finite groups and their applications to combinatorics](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1979-01-03/S0273-0979-1979-14597-X/),"  Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 1 (1979), 475–511. His example 3.6 is a cyclic group of order 4.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the action of the cyclic group $G$ of order $n$ acting on an $m$-dimensional vector space $V$.  I'll assume you are working over an algebraically closed field $k$ (or at least a field containing the nth roots of unity).  Over such a field the elements of the cyclic group are diagonalizable.  Thus the group is generated by $g=\diag(\omega^{-a_1},\dots,\omega^{-a_m})$ where $\omega$ is a primitive nth root of unity and the $a_i$ are integers (which may be assumed to lie between 0 and $n-1$.

If $\{x_1,\dots,x_m\}$ is a basis for $V^*$ dual to the diagonal basis for $V$, then $g$ acts via $g\cdot x_i = \omega^{a_i} x_i$.  Hence if $t = x_1^{e_1}\cdots x_m^{e_m}$ is a monomial then
$g\cdot t = \omega^{a_1e_1 + \cdots a_me_m} t$.  Since a function is invariant iff it is a linear combination of invariant monomials, the invariant theory reduces to solving the linear congruence
$a_1e_1 + \cdots a_me_m \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$ for $(e_1,\dots,e_m)$.  These solutions form a monoid in $N^m$.  Finding a set of minimal generators for $k[V]^G$ amounts to finding minimal generators for this monoid.  This is not really solved in general but there has been a lot of study, as you might imagine.

I suggest the following references.

Weidong Gao, Alfred Geroldinger,
Zero-sum problems in finite abelian groups: A survey,
Expo. Math. 24 (2006) 337 – 369

John C. Harris and David L. Wehlau,
Non-Negative Integer Linear Congruences,
Indagationes Mathematicae {\bf 17} No. 1 (2006) 37-44.  arXiv:math/0409489v1

Pingzhi Yuan,
On the index of minimal zero-sum sequences over finite cyclic groups,
Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A 114 (2007) 1545–1551

Finally, I'll mention that things are much much more complicated (equivalent to the invariant theory of SL(2,C)) when the characteristic of $k$ divides $n$.